# MySQL Merge records with boolean values

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL statement that returns a set of records:

```
SELECT
  members.id,
  members.name,
  emlink.tank,
  emlink.dps,
  emlink.heal,
  emlink.mid,
  emlink.eid
FROM 
  members, emlink
WHERE members.id = $mid AND emlink.eid = $eid
```

Result:

```
1 Widget 0 0 1 1 8

1 Widget 1 0 0 1 8
```

How can I merge these into a single record like:

```
1 Widget 1 0 1 1 8
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: I have a feeling that you are not joining tables correctly here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want a bitwise `OR`?  If so, use MySQL's [`BIT_OR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or) aggregate function:

```
SELECT members.id,
       members.name,
       BIT_OR(emlink.tank),
       BIT_OR(emlink.dps ),
       BIT_OR(emlink.heal),
       BIT_OR(emlink.mid ),
       BIT_OR(emlink.eid )
FROM   members, emlink
WHERE  members.id = $mid AND emlink.eid = $eid
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25f2c/1/0).

Comment: wouldnt you need a group by statement here?

Comment: @gbtimmon: [*If you use a group function in a statement containing no `GROUP BY` clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: mySQL just has to make everything easy doesnt it :P

Comment: Yes! this produced the desired result:1
Widget 1 0 1 1 8

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.id,
       M.name,
       MAX (E.tank),
       MAX (E.dps),
       MAX (E.heal),
       MAX (E.mid),
       E.eid
  FROM members M,
       emlink E
  WHERE M.id = $mid 
    AND E.eid = $eid
  GROUP BY M.id, M.name, E.eid
```

Or whatever aggreagate function most fits your needs, SUM, MAX, BIT_OR etc

Comment: Given the question's title ("*merge records with **binary** values*" - my emphasis), my hunch is that it's a bitwise operation.  PS - [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is not an aggregate function.

Comment: Also you making big assumptions on the data type here though. Without that your answer is as good as any other.

Comment: My fault, I am working with boolean values I just want to set a field to 1 from 0.  I'm not working with binary.  The MAX() function dosn't seem to exist in mysql version I'm using. This example produces the following error: #1630 - FUNCTION OA.MAX does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual